# How to read Python array from file?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to write and read Python array from a txt file. I know to how to write it, but reading the array requires me to provide an argument about the length of the array. I do not the length of the array in advance, is there a way to read the array without computing its length. My work in progress code below. If I provide 1 as the second argument in a.fromfile, it reads the first element of the array, I would like all elements to read (basically the array to be recreated).

```
from __future__ import division
from array import array

L = [1,2,3,4]
indexes = array('I', L)

with open('indexes.txt', 'w') as fileW:
    indexes.tofile(fileW)

a = array('I', [])
with open('indexes.txt', 'r') as fileR:
    a.fromfile(fileR,1)
```

Comment: Did you come from a different programming language? because in python we don't need to define the size of the array, we can just create the list and we use `list`

Comment: please also try to provide us the sample content of `indexes.txt` so we can check what seems to be the problem

Comment: It would also be good if you explain why you want to use `array` rather than `list`.

Comment: If you want to do this with binary data, I think the easy way to determine the array size is to compute it from the file size. There are funcfions in the `os` module that can get the file size efficiently.

Comment: I use an array to save memory, I am working on a large problem

Comment: This should have been closed because it makes no sense (it fundamentally confuses text and binary files), but it is not a duplicate (the expected file format does not match - it seems that a binary format was intended).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why `.fromfile` asks you to specify a number of objects but `.frombytes` doesn't. You can just read the bytes from the file and append them to the array.

This works in python3:

```
with open('indexes.txt', 'rb') as fileR:
    a.frombytes(fileR.read())
print(a)
```

prints:

```
array('I', [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

In python2 there is no `.frombytes` but `.fromstring` since `str` is equivalent to python3 `bytes`:

```
with open('indexes.txt', 'rb') as fileR: 
    a.fromstring(fileR.read())
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.7
When I used you code, it tells me I cannot use "br", when I replace it with "r", I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'frombytes'

Comment: @user58925 I made a bit of a mess, now it should work.

Comment: works perfect, thanks